# Time expected Facebook API Realtime

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

Anyone that is using Facebook Realtime API has noticed a delay on receiving the updates? The API documentation says:

"Changes are aggregated and sent in batch at most once every 5 seconds, or when the number of unsent changes exceeds 1000 - your server callback should be able to handle this level of load."

However im experiencing longer periods than this promised 5 seconds. Is there anything i should check to ensure that the problem is with me and not Facebook? Or its normal this longer duration than advertised?

Comment: At **most** every 5 seconds - how often is the content you're subscribed to being updated?

Comment: Like once in a day, whats your experience?

Comment: but how often is the content being updated? It sounds like you're saying you're not getting 'enough' updates - are updates taking place for which you receive no notification, but should have?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the facebook API spec at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1 states **at most** every 5 seconds.

In my experience it can be up to 10 min when their realtime endpoint is getting wonky. If you stop receiving updates all together and can't debug it for the life of you, check the bug reports--their realtime API has gone out for weeks at a time, more than once.